# New column in dataframe with values from the max row of GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where each row represents a different stock for every day of October. The dataframe has multiple columns. Three of them are `Stock_id`, `Date`, `Stock_value`.

I want to find the stock which has the maximum value for each day of October and insert its `Stock_id` as a value at each row to a new column in my dataframe.

So let's say that I have this:

[image]

and then I want to have this somehow:

[image]

Please keep in mind that these above are sample inputs and desired outputs. To start with, each 'Stock_id' has a row for each date of October.

I guess that the solution the problem will involve something like `data_daily.groupby(['Date'])['Stock_value']` but with something more apparently or it may be something entirely different in total.

How can I do this?

Comment: `data_daily['max_group'] = data_daily.groupby(['Date'])['Stock_value'].transform('max')` ?

Comment: @DanielMesejo no read carefully my post.

Comment: Could you share a small input *resembling* your data-frame, and also the expected output.

Comment: Can you please provide [MCVE] ?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, I edited my post

Comment: @jezrael any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
transform = df.groupby('Date')['Stock_value'].transform('idxmax')
df['Max_Stock_id'] = df.iloc[transform, 0].values

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Stock_id       Date  Stock_value  Max_Stock_id
0       963 2018-02-10         97.5           963
1      1201 2018-02-10         91.1           963
2      1341 2018-03-10         93.7          1341
3      1458 2018-03-10         92.6          1341
```

Comment: I think that it works :) and actually also before your edit with that `data_daily['Max_Stock_id'] = data_daily['Store_id'].values[transform]`. What is the difference with your edit?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit I think this is a more clear way, just that.

Comment: Yes it looks better now. These numpy things were confusing me a bit. But both work in any case. Thank you :)

Comment: By the way, just for the sake of knowledge, why do you need the `.values`?

Comment: I know that I am getting an error (`raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`) if I remove this but I am just asking because it is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: So you received the same error and this is why your are using `.values` or is it a general rule for something in pandas?

Comment: I received the same error and use .values, because then it only uses the values.

Comment: Ok so it is not (or at least you do not know if this is) a general rule in pandas that you have to use .values in this case and in similar cases? Pandas confuses me a bit in these cases when indexing dataframes and assigning new data etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187674/discussion-between-daniel-mesejo-and-poete-maudit).